# Fire a javascript event when textbox is autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I need to enable a button when a textbox is filled. However no javascript event is fired when you fill the textbox using the browser *autocomplete* function, so I need a way to catch this "event". I tryed many javascript events like *change*  *focus* but they aren't fired when you select and option in the autocomplete "combo".

```
$('#mytextbox').on('change', function(){
   $('#mybutton').removeAttr('disbled');
});
```

Comment: Don't this it's possible, [this article](http://avernet.blogspot.nl/2010/11/autocomplete-and-javascript-change.html) explains why. Check out the workarounds too.

Comment: @a_maar, You can do this in alternate way. Instead of try to capture event in action of auto-complete overlay, Go one step backward and listen key event on textbox. Since auto-complete trigger based on key-down event, you can enable/disable button based on key event by checking whether the textbox is empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to use jquery ui autocomplete ?

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox